# What is the modern general communication language writing system with simplest letter symbols?

Tags: writing-systems, minimalism, korean

I would like to know what is the modern, formal, writing system with simplest (most minimal) letter symbols by these means:

- Total number of letters comprised only or mostly from [line segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment) (horizontal, vertical or both) and/or circles
- Total number of letters comprised from the lowest number of [polygon dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) per letter (3 dots)

> Because no writing system I know is made only or mostly from line segments and/or circles; there are usually always letters with `three ≥ plygon dots` also.

Note: Every font that isn't loyal mathematically to the formal `font-pattern` of the language (a recursive font would be an harsh example) isn't counted.

---

I personally recognize English, Arabic, Modern Hebrew, and Modern South Korean writing system (South Korean [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul)) as the most minimal writing systems I know by means of line segments and polygons.

South Korean Hangul, for example:

> **19 Consonants:** `ㄱㄲㄴㄷㄸㄹㅁㅂㅃㅅㅆㅇㅈㅉㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎ`
>   **10 Vowels:** `ㅏ ㅑ ㅓ ㅔ ㅗ ㅛ ㅜ ㅠ ㅡ ㅣ`
>   **11 Vowel combinations:** `ㅐ  ㅒ  ㅕ ㅖ ㅘ ㅙ ㅚ ㅝ ㅞ ㅟ ㅢ`

### My problem

A strict determination requires vast comparative linguistics knowledge that I don't have.

### My question

What is the modern general communication language writing system with simplest (most minimal) letter symbols?

Comment: Does Morse code count? Braille?

Comment: Braille yes --- about Morse code I don't know ; I edited the question to better explain my original meaning, please re-read at least the title.

Comment: I would say that it's questionable whether Latin has the "most minimal" letters (in quantity or quality)... Greek must at least be pretty close, with also less of a penchant for fancy typefaces with serifs, and simple curves in the modern lowercase. I'd say the answer to your question, empirically, is mostly: 1) the creation of alphabets, as opposed to syllabaries or pictograms 2) the printing press in Europe creating an incentive for simplified, unconnected letter forms (connected letter forms make Arabic a bit trickier for instance, but if you look at Latin cursive, that's the same).

Comment: Then Hangul is sort of a case on its own... (it's used in North Korea too, by the way, it's not just South Korean.) Unlike most writing systems in actual use by vast amounts of people, it was created artificially, with some phonetics concepts in mind and explicitly striving to be a simple system to learn. Subjectively, I consider it brilliant. It's also partly a featural alphabet, which is again rare in widely-used writing systems. If these comments sound like an answer to you, I guess I can reframe them as an answer; I'm not sure myself.

Comment: It's absolutely not clear, not from the answer and comments either, what you understand as *simple*.

Comment: @vectory `Number of polygon dots per letter` --- no writing system is made only from `line segment`s (horizontal, vertical or both); there are usually always letter with more than 3 polygons, or circle.

Comment: ... or applied linguistics, if ease of production is a concern. Cursive isn't even really taught in the US, I hear.

Comment: @vectory hello again - I have edited the question several times due to your comment - I can only hope the question is now clearer.

Comment: @JohnDoea I don't think so, but it goes to show that defining simplicity is quite complicated. You might enjoy the irony. You give the circle "special status", so to say, but what it C? It's not a circle, yet it's not typically a sequences of straight lines. That's just one example, and just from one alphabet, but there are countless types of curves in scripts, sometimes with curved segments being much more prominent than straight ones.

Comment: @curiousdannii Morse code is not a writing system.

Comment: @Keelan hmm, this is a bit tangential, but I think originally, Morse code was fully intended to be (automatically) transcribed and then read by the operator from paper. Since it contains symbols for each letter of the Latin alphabet, it's arguably either a writing system, or at least a transliteration system for Latin. Then, later, they realized that operators would just learn to transcribe much more quickly "by ear"... but that was not originally envisioned.

Comment: @LjL can you support those claims? Since CW is defined by timing it really seems transcription is secondary. Also in the time that it was invented automatic transcription would have been difficult...

Comment: @Keelan as I said, automatic transcription was initially the default. It wasn't difficult, the current being created by the sending party closing the circuit would cause a coil to move on your end, which supported a pen, which inked a strip of paper moving at a constant speed. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Morse_code#/media/File:The_First_Telegraph.jpg) is a copy of the first telegram ever sent, and you can see (faintly) that there are Morse grooves above the transcribed letter, although they are uninked in this case...

Comment: ... [Here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Development_and_history) it says "The Morse system for telegraphy, which was first used in about 1844, was designed to make indentations on a paper tape when electric currents were received. Morse's original telegraph receiver used a mechanical clockwork to move a paper tape. When an electrical current was received, an electromagnet engaged an armature that pushed a stylus onto the moving paper tape, making an indentation on the tape." — This is the original reason why the types of Morse signals are called "dots" and "dashes".

Comment: @LjL if you read on, you read that very soon this method became a backup only and operators relied on their ear. So yes, you might call the original version a transcription method (thanks, I didn't know that), but I maintain that it is confusing to categorise it as such for the past 150 years or so.

Comment: @Keelan uhm, well, and if *you* read my comment you responded to, it fully covered that by saying "Then, later, they realized that operators would just learn to transcribe much more quickly 'by ear'... but that was not originally envisioned" ;-) What you decide to categorize it as is your choice, but I thought I was just providing some food for thought about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cree syllabics seems to the be simplest by any count. The letters ᐊ  ᐸ  ᑕ  ᑲ  ᒐ ᒪ ᓇ  ᓴ  ᔭ represent the consonants Ø p  t  k  ch  m  n  s  y (this is the "a" form), and vowels are indicated by the orientation of the basic shape, so ᐸ ᐯ ᐱ   ᐳ is respectively [pa pe pi po]. The rule for orientation is not entirely trivial: it involves flipping or rotation, so compare the series [ka ke ki ko] = ᑲ ᑫ ᑭ ᑯ .

Comment: Hi, your answer let me think about Turkic and Nordic runes as well.

Comment: Well, for me, runes only seem to be simple, since there are few character (younger futhark at least), but each of them may represent much more than one sound, like ᚢ, which represents /u/, /o/, /y/ (and all their nasal counterparts) and /v///w/

Answer (score 0):

The cursive alphabet scripts, be it German, Russian or Arabic are dead simple to produce. The results are not always pretty, sometimes impossible to read.

Realisation is rarely considered in linguistics, and in that sense the Latin alphabet is just an abstract map of twentysix phonemes to one arbitrary symbol each. I mean, font variants may be arbitrary. That's where your question fails.

The German cursive system's majuscles with personal modifications are pretty minimal with only three basic forms: circle, downward stroke, and bow; each drawn out to various extent. Whereas hooks, dots and horizontal strokes are added features that are minimal in size. e and s are outstanding variations of the basic idea as they are the and respectively one of the most frequent letters. x and z diverge further from the basic idea, but they rarely stand out, as they are relatively rare, x much more so than z. I don't know what's up with k though. It really should be c with downward stroke. And ß, let's just ignore it.

Here's a *minimal* example.

.[image]

A similar one exists in Russian. All Arabic looks like that to me

Comment: Thanks! `Realisation`?

Comment: I voted to close this question as too broad. As it stands, I should have chosen opinion based, because it depends on what font you like.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by realisation --- I think I quite "mathematically" described what I mean --- formal letter systems (every font that isn't loyal mathematically isn't counted).

Comment: "(transitive, linguistics) To turn an abstract linguistic object into actual language, especially said of a phoneme's conversion into speech sound" [[wiki/realization](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/realize)]